# what is the difference between L1 norm, absolute value and absolute value norm?

Tags: normed-spaces

|x| is one the most common symbol in math. it seems that this symbol means a some different computation.

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Absolute-value_norm)

> The absolute value norm is a special case of the $L1$ norm.

[absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a real number x is the non-negative value of x without regard to its sign.

For example, the absolute value of 3 is 3, and the absolute value of −3 is also 3.

can anyone give an simple example to elaborate the difference between L1 norm, absolute value and absolute value norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute value and absolute value norm are defined only for numbers (usually for complex or reals). $L_1$ norm is defined for functional space with measure.

Any finite dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^n$ is functional space - it's elements can be viewed as functions from $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to \mathbb R$. We can introduce [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and get $L_1$ norm on $\mathbb{R^n}$: $\|(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\| = |x_1| + \ldots + |x_n|$.

$\mathbb R$ itself can be viewed as one-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, and thus we will get $L_1$ norm $\|x\| = |x|$.

There is no significant difference between absolute value and absolute value norm - they are the same function(s). Term "absolute value norm" is more often used when we want to emphasize that we work with vector space, and "absolute value" when we work with just numbers.